# Compile ffmpeg with AMR decoding

Tags: android, ffmpeg, amr

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg for Android to convert amr files to wav. So I ran:

`./configure --help |grep arm`

and I'm getting:

`--enable-libopencore-amrnb enable AMR-NB de/encoding via libopencore-amrnb [no]
  --enable-libopencore-amrwb enable AMR-WB decoding via libopencore-amrwb [no]
  --enable-libvo-amrwbenc  enable AMR-WB encoding via libvo-amrwbenc [no]`

So for decoding amr I think I should use --enable-libopencore-amrwb in my configure script, right? But when I add it to my configure script, I get:

```
ERROR: libopencore_amrwb not found
```

What should I do? Should I download opencore-amr library and put source code anywhere? Or there is other way to get amr decoding in ffmpeg?

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll post questions like this at Super User

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### External libraries

External library support requires the external library as a dependency. So its headers and any other required files must be available during `ffmpeg` compilation.

#### Native decoders exist

However, FFmpeg has native support for decoding AMR-WB and AMR-NB, so you probably won't need these external libraries unless they offer features not present in the native decoders.

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i amr
 D..... = Decoding supported
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ....L. = Lossy compression
 -------
 D.A.L. amr_nb               AMR-NB (Adaptive Multi-Rate NarrowBand) (decoders:amrnb )
 D.A.L. amr_wb               AMR-WB (Adaptive Multi-Rate WideBand) (decoders: amrwb )
```